# Tengo problemas para "clonar" un proyecto para hacer una versión "pro"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play

Es mi primera vez en esto, y quiero subir a Play Store dos aplicaciones, que son las mismas, con la diferencia de que una versión "pro" y la otra normal.

Entonces lo que hice fue copiar el proyecto y renombrar los paquetes y el nombre, pero a la hora de correr las apps en mi teléfono se sobrescriben (no se instalan las 2 al mismo tiempo).

En mi caso ¿Es lo más recomendable hacer lo que estoy haciendo?, y en caso de que sea así ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? Gracias.

Comment: Mira Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada aplicación es definida por un identificador único que es `applicationId`

```
android {
    ...
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.luisquesada.app"
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

no puede existir en la tienda Google Play dos aplicaciones con el mismo `applicationId`:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luisquesada.app

tampoco puedes instalar 2 aplicaciones diferentes con el mismo  `applicationId`   ya que esta sera sobreescrita.

**por lo tanto tienes que crear 2 aplicaciones con diferente  `applicationId` o package name**